# Is it possible to restrict who can complete a Pull Request in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

We are just moving from another Git-Repo-Hosting-system to Azure DevOps. In the previous system it was possible to restrict who is allowed to complete a pull request (assuming that all findings are resolved). That means the Pull request was "ready" to be merged but only specific people had the permissions to actually execute the merge.

Looking through the documentation of Azure DevOps I have not found such a feature out-of-the-box.
Did I simply miss it or it is not possible at all?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel's right.  [Branch policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops) already do exactly what you're saying. Policies enforce your team's code quality and change management standards.

You just need to use Require a minimum number of reviewers:

[image]

**When the required number of reviewers approve the pull request, it can finish.**

Also expand with more detail info and show you a example how will this works in your side. Image you have two teams:

**Developers:**

- Patrick
- Carl
- ......
- [project]\PM and Developer Managers

**PM and Developer Managers:**

- PM
- Developer Managers

One could add the **PM and Developer Managers:** team as "required" on the branch policy, and keep the **Developers** team rights to pull requests, allowing other develops to still approve requests and comment etc.

But the request can't be completed until a user in PM and Developer Managers group approves it.

Comment: This does restrict a PR from being completed until it is fully approved, but it's still a workaround if you want to restrict who can fill in the final "complete PR" screen.
To my knowledge there is no way you can set who is allowed to fill that screen, and e.g. make sure that the right Merge Type gets picked or that they delete the source branch.

Comment: This isn't sufficient at all.  If you have a large project with a ton of PRs coming in, you sometimes want to be strategic about which PRs are merged and in what order.  And to do that it's common to have one person designated for completing merges.  Branch policies don't accommodate for that.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [branch policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops). Branch policies let you designate the circumstances under which a PR can be merged, including required approvers and builds.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the person responsible for completing the Pull Request (PR) a Required reviewer, you can control when the PR completes. Essentially that Required reviewer would be the last person to approve, then they could click "Complete".

That is the way I have personally done it.

Comment: I know this but it is not about "Approving" to complete but actually doing the complete itself. Anyway thank you for the answer.